# Get storyboard from app.xaml and set target programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to get an animation from app.xaml (move a label up/down, like a message popup). Though, when I try to get the storyboard

app.xaml:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="AnimatedMessage">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                Duration="0:0:10"
                                AutoReverse="True">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="100" KeyTime="0:0:2"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="200" KeyTime="0:0:4"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="300" KeyTime="0:0:6"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

My backend:

```
Storyboard SBStartAnimation = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("AnimatedMessage");
Storyboard.SetTarget(SBStartAnimation, LBAnimateMessage);
SBStartAnimation.Begin(this);
```

But it blames me, I can't set an attribute to storyboard-object because it is read-only.

UPDATE:

My label what I like to animate:

`<Label Content="" Name="LBAnimateMessage" Visibility="Hidden" Width="600" Style="{StaticResource Style_BasicMessage}" Margin="10,303,235,38"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are trying to set the Storyboard's target, rather than setting it's animation's. Try `Storyboard.SetTarget(SBStartAnimation.Children.First(), LBAnimateMessage);`

Don't forget that `LBAnimateMessage` has to be of `PropertyPath` property.

EDIT: Correction, PropertyPath is for SetTargetProperty.

Comment: Hi Dracor, it didn't work with `Storyboard.SetTarget(SBStartAnimation.Children.First(), LBAnimateMessage);` How can I make sure my Label `LBAnimateMessage` is part of the `PropertyPath`?

Comment: In that case, just construct a new Storyboard from code, that should do the trick.

Comment: You can also try moving the Storyboard from app.xaml to the page/window xaml

Comment: with the app.xaml I tried to create a global storyboard ... with window.xaml it's not so global anymore.